# How can I make it so that a texture displacement applies to all sides of an object?

Tags: texturing, modifiers, displacement

I am using a height map as a texture for a displacement in a cube, but the only sides that are displaced properly are the top and bottom. The other sides don't have the texture applied to them, they only have lines that kind of make to look like the displacement is only being applied on the Z Axis. How can I make it so that the displacement shows up on all sides of the cube?[image: The sides are weird][image: The height map I'm using]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the *'Texture coordinates'* to UV, and eventually choose a UV map:

[image]

[image]